# Limit of $\frac{1}{n} (\sqrt{ \frac{1}{n}} + \sqrt{ \frac{2}{n}} + \sqrt{ \frac{3}{n}} + ... + 1 )$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I've got problems with calculating the limit in this example:
Some help or hints please:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n\left[ \sqrt\frac 1n +\sqrt\frac 2n + \dots + \sqrt\frac nn
\right]
$$

Comment: Do you know what a Riemann sum is?

Comment: Is the limit is known as the Riemann integral of f(x) over the interval  [a,b] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [the wikipedia page about Riemann sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum).

It tells you that if
$$
a=x_{0,n}<\dots < x_{n,n}=b
\\
x^*_{k,n}\in [x_{k,n},x_{k+1,n}]
$$then
$$
\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n f(x^*_{k,n}) [x_{k+1,n} - x_{k,n}]
\to \int_a^b f(t) dt.
$$

Here $x^*_{k,n} = x_{k,n} = k/n, f(x) = \sqrt(x)$.

Comment: if the downvoter could explain...

Comment: @mookid There's been rogue downvoters lately; both answers in this thread were downvoted

Comment: @mookid, it happens from time to time. In the last days I have a "groupie" downvoting my answers...go figure. For long time I've argued that downvoters *should* be forced, by the site, to write a little note explaining their downvotes, but it seems unlikely this will happen soon...

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt\frac kn\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\int\limits_0^1\sqrt x\,dx=\;\ldots$$

Comment: if you do not mind, could you explain a little more ?? thanx

Comment: take as your partition intervals of width $\frac{1}{n}$